# Azure AppCenter: Android build succeeds but no APKs found

Tags: android, azure, visual-studio-app-center

I've been setting up Azure App Center build pipelines and after some troubleshooting, I managed to make our debug build succeed. The issue is that, it seems to not be able to find any of the generated APKs in the expected directories. Any ideas on why that is?

Here's the specific part of the output log:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4m 28s 130 actionable tasks: 124 executed, 6
> up-to-date
> ##[section]Finishing: Gradle Task
> ##[section]Starting: Android Postprocess
> ============================================================================== Task         : Shell script Description  : Run a shell script using
> Bash Version      : 2.206.0 Author       : Microsoft Corporation Help
> :
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script
> ============================================================================== [command]/bin/bash
> /Users/runner/runners/2.206.1/scripts/android-postprocess.sh
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/build/outputs/apk Removing all ABI or density
> dependent APKs… find: /Users/runner/work/1/s/build/outputs/apk: No
> such file or directory find: /Users/runner/work/1/s/build/outputs/apk:
> No such file or directory find:
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/build/outputs/apk: No such file or directory
> Found        0 APK file(s) Found        0 unaligned APK file(s) find:
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/build/outputs/apk: No such file or directory
> /Users/runner/runners/2.206.1/scripts/android-postprocess.sh: line 36:
> pushd: /Users/runner/work/1/s/build/outputs/apk/..: No such file or
> directory
> /Users/runner/runners/2.206.1/scripts/android-postprocess.sh: line 43:
> popd: directory stack empty
> ##[error]The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
> ##[error]Bash failed with error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
> ##[section]Finishing: Android Postprocess

I also have a post-clone bash script for generating the `local.properties` file which contains some secrets, and it seems to work just fine since the build uses it and goes through with it.

Sadly, I can't infer much from the logs, I'm not a DevOps engineer and have practically 0 experience in this sector.

Comment: Hey, can you post your pipeline code?

Comment: @PineapplePie Hi, sorry for the late reply. There is no pipeline code that I've written when using App Center. It mitigates the need of writing such basic tasks by providing ready made ones through its web interface.

Answer (score 0):

The AppCenter is looking at /Users/runner/work/1/s/build/outputs/apk for an APK.
/Users/runner/work/1/s is like the project folder where AppCenter has checked out your sources.

Find out what your project.buildDir is (it can be configured in a build.gradle file). You can do so by building your project locally and check where the .apk file is created.

Set the project.buildDir to build/outputs/apk. Now AppCenter should find it.